# Can the Walsh Hadamard transform be computed for non power of 2 sizes?

Tags: image-processing, filters, dct

Can the walsh hadamard transform be calculated for odd image block sizes such as 5x5 or 7x7? Most of the examples I've seen are for 4x4 and 8x8?

I fear it probably can't from the description I read on Wikipedia ( though I'm still trying to fully digest that page).

Comment: I know this is not answering your question, but how about padding your block with zeros? Working with powers of 2 is always comforting!

Comment: @AtulIngle That is a very bad idea in the context of the Walsh-Hadamard transform.

Comment: Just for completeness @dilip, why would it be a bad idea?

Comment: The DFT method of computing a convolution always gives the _cyclic_ or circular convolution of the input sequences. It is adapted to compute the _linear_ convolution of sequences of lengths $L$ and $M$, say, by zero-padding the sequences to common length $N \geq L+M-1$ where $N$ is chosen so as to be able to use the FFT algorithm for the DFT most efficiently. The Walsh-Hadmard transform supports a _different_ convolution, and _cannot_ be used to compute linear convolutions via zero-padding. So, you _could_ zero-pad, and use the FHT, but is $\mathbf xH$ really useful for anything?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Walsh-Hadamard transform requires a Hadamard matrix -- which has entries $\pm 1$ and
whose rows are orthogonal vectors.  A $n \times n$ Hadamard matrix is known to exist
for $n = 2$. Larger Hadamard matrices can exist only if $n$ is a multiple of $4$, though
it is not known if there is a Hadamard matrix for *every* multiple of $4$. However,
there is a *recursive* construction that can be used to construct a $2^m \times 2^m$
Hadamard matrix from a $2^{m-1}\times 2^{m-1}$ Hadamard matrix, and this structure 
allows for the use of the *Fast Hadamard Transform* algorithm, which reduces the
computational cost from $2^{2m}$ additions and subtractions to $m2^m$ additions and
subtractions (just like the $N$-FFT reduces the number of multiplications from
$O(N^2)$ to $O(N\log N)$.

With this as background, the answer is Yes, you can use a Walsh-Hadamard transform
of length $N$ if you can find a $N\times N$ Hadamard matrix, but your choices
for $N$ are necessarily restricted. Also, *fast* algorithms may not exist
for your choice of $N$, though *some* speed-up is usually possible.

Note that Walsh-Hadamard transforms (WHTs) do *not* support cyclic convolutions, but
they do support what is sometimes called Poisson convolution. If $H$ denotes 
a $2^m\times 2^m$
Hadamard matrix and $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ are vectors of length $2^m$ with \WHTs $\mathbf xH$ and $\mathbf yH$,
then the *inverse WHT* of the *term-by-term* multiplication of the entries
in $\mathbf xH$ and $\mathbf yH$ can be described as follows.  Suppose that the entries in
$\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ etc are indexed not by integers $0$ through $2^m-1$ but rather
by the $m$-bit representations of these numbers.  Thus, we talk not of
$x[k]$ as the $k$-th entry in $\mathbf x$ but rather of $x[\mathbf k]$ where
$\mathbf k$ is the $m$-bit representation of $k$.  Then, the iWHT of the term-by-term
product of the entries in $\mathbf xH$ and $\mathbf yH$ has $\mathbf k$-th entry
$$\sum_{\mathbf i} x[\mathbf i]y[\mathbf k\oplus \mathbf i]$$
which is eerily reminiscent of
$$\sum_i x[i]y[k-i]$$
and even more so if one notes that modulo two, addition and subtraction
are the same and so that $\mathbf k\oplus \mathbf i$ could as well
have been written as $\mathbf k\ominus \mathbf i$.

Comment: Many thanks for the extremely detailed response

Comment: I never knew these things about the WHT. Thanks!