# Understanding Walsh coefficients

Tags: fourier-transform, transform

I am working with Walsh coefficients.

I know the intuitive understanding is almost that that they are the degree of connectivity, but it is there a better way of thinking about it? What is the definition of a Walsh coefficient besides "What you get when you take the Walsh transform".

Thanks

Comment: Since you give no information as to _where_ and _why_ you are calculating Walsh coefficients, it is hard to frame an answer to your question. Some basic information about Walsh transforms (but possibly irrelevant to your application) can be found in [this recent answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/7965/235) on dsp.SE