# Other Examples of Complete Orthonormal Systems

Tags: coding, orthornormal, cdma

I am interested in other examples of finite and complete orthogonal basis. I am not confident in my use of the term “complete”, so what I mean specifically is a set of basis vectors that can be used in a transformation from one domain (or vector space) to another with no loss, duplication or distortion in the transformation. (A constant scaling factor is acceptable, hence not restricted to being “orthonormal”.)

Two examples I am familiar with (which related to communication systems is the difference between OFDMA and CDMA):

**OFDMA:** The set of exponentials in the Discrete Fourier Transform mapping N samples in time to N samples in frequency using $e^{j  2\pi n/N}$ for $n = 0$ to $N-1$, which has the following resulting code set with $W_N^{nk} = (e^{j/N})^{nk}$:

$$W_N  = \begin{bmatrix} W_N^0 & W_N^0 & \ldots & W_N^0\\
                        W_N^0 & W_N^1 & \ldots & W_N^{N-1}\\ 
                        \vdots  & \vdots  &  & \vdots \\
                         W_N^0 & W_N^{N-1} & \ldots & W_N^{(N-1)^2} \\  \end{bmatrix}$$

as a matrix with each row indexed by $k$ for $k=0 \ldots N-1$ and each column indexed by $n$  for $n = 0 \ldots N-1$.

Note that $$W_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\1 & -1\ \end{bmatrix}$$

**CDMA:** The set of Walsh-Hadamard Codes mapping N samples in time to N samples in a $W_N$ code space   , with a resulting code set built on the pattern:

$$W_N  = \begin{bmatrix} W_{N-1} & W_{N-1}\\W_{N-1} & -W_{N-1}\ \end{bmatrix}$$

With $$W_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\1 & -1\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Interesting to me is the observation that both start of with the same 2 element form, but the DFT expands using the complex plane into possible elements all on the unit circle, while the Walsh-Hadamard codes commonly used for CDMA are limited to two elements (+1 and -1). In particular, I am looking for the possibility of other known finite and complete orthogonal code sets that also use the complex plane, but more samples beyond the unit circle, or alternatively the reason why such codes can't exist.

Comment: The Walsh-Hadamard Transform does not support the familiar cyclic convolution that the DFT supports, but instead something that can be called Poisson convolution (cf.  the latter half of [this answer of mine](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/7965/235)).

Comment: @DilipSarwate That is interesting! Thanks. I'm sure you must know of other codes, and was hoping you would see this and have an answer for below. (limited to finite ones is important, and ideally but not necessarily from the complex plane)

Comment: Dan, what do you mean by "complete"? And just to make sure I understand, any non-singular matrix maps one vector space to another. But surely this is not what you mean?

Comment: @MBaz I was looking for the correct term and not confident I found it. Parseval's Theorem is an example on how the DFT is complete. It's a lossless transform where we represent the information completely in either domain (Consider how if you add the complex Kernel's for each bin in the DFT that it adds to 1 everywhere in the frequency domain; all energy is preserved). The CDMA example I give does the same thing, just with a different frequency response for each code. So it needs to do this, and for each of the codes to be orthogonal, which isn't the case for any non-singular matrix.

Comment: I am thinking of the family of discrete cosine and sine transforms, as well as the Hartley transform. There exist complex versions of Hadamard/Haar matrices.  And orthogonal,discrete wavelets

Comment: @LaurentDuval yes I was curious about the wavelet cases and if that could suggest next generation waveforms, please elaborate as an answer when you have time if you know more! (As well as you other suggestions. Interesting, thanks!

Comment: @DanBoschen My understanding of a "complete" basis is that it allows representation of a specific set of functions with vanishing error. For example, the FT can represent the set of periodic functions that meet certain mathematical conditions. It's possible the term you're looking for is "lossless", or maybe "energy preserving".

Comment: @DanBoschen we're looking for transforms from N-dimensional complex to N-dimensional complex vectors, right? Or is it OK if the other domain has larger dimension than N?

Comment: @MarcusMüller my view may be too narrow so open to other thoughts but was considering specifically with the comparison of CDMA (3G) to OFDM (4G+) where in both cases we map N complex symbols using a set of N orthogonal codes- so I wanted to have a better understanding of what other options were out there that would also provide the same purpose and maybe other advantages for comm.

Comment: nonono, that's not too narrowing, on the contrary, if we included k->n mappings (n>k), then we'd suddenly be in for a lot of channel codes which would arguably not be what you're looking for

Comment: +1 I'm particularly interested in transforms that also have a continuous-time interpolation inverse similar to FT's sinc, which would aid with [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/83021/50076). I've asked on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/422548/396854)